# Bot sending messages when reacting to both reactions on the same message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

```py
mstatus = True

for mem in members:
  memberreact = await mem.user.send("do you wish to approve  or decline?\nchoose ⬆️ to approve and ⬇️ to decline!!")

  await memberreact.add_reaction("⬆️")
  await memberreact.add_reaction("⬇️")

  def mcheck1(reaction, user):
    return user == mem.user and reaction.message.id == memberreact.id and str(reaction.emoji) == "⬆️"
  def mcheck2(reaction, user):
    return user == mem.user and reaction.message.id == memberreact.id and str(reaction.emoji) == "⬇️"

  async def mreact1(mstatus):
    #first logic
    if mstatus == True:
      reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=mcheck1)
      await mem.user.send("you have approved!!")
      mstatus = False
      print(mstatus)
  async def mreact2(mstatus):
    #second logic
    if mstatus == True:
      reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=mcheck2)
      await mem.user.send("you have decline!!")
      mstatus = False
      print(mstatus)
     
  await asyncio.gather(mreact1(mstatus), mreact2(mstatus))
```

This code giving me the first logic when reacting to ⬆️ and giving me second logic when reacting to ⬇️ in the **same message**. But that doesn't make sense because mstatus in the code goes False when reacting to ⬆️ at first. Is there any problem in this code?

Answer (score 0):

You did a typo, it's simple:

```py
async def mreact1(mstatus):
   if mstatus == True:
      reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=mcheck1)
      await mem.user.send("you have approved!!")
      mstatus = False ## SHOULD BE TRUE!!!!!
      print(mstatus)
```

Comment: Wait uhhh.. What's the diff with this code from mine..? Sorry i can't find any..

Comment: @arielle it looks like the code is the same but there’s a comment saying you should change a `False` to `True`.